# issue with screen resolution

Tags: android, screen, resolution

Through programming how can i know whats the `screen resolution` of my screen.
As soon as run the app it should find out the `screen resolution` in `dp and in pixel`.

How can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to get screen info from your device.

Some sample code,

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

final int height = dm.heightPixels;
final int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

**EDIT:**

```
float xDpi =   dm.xdpi;
float yDpi =   dm.ydpi;

float density = dm.density;
```

Comment: I edited my answer, For more look at the link, of Display Metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get screen width & height

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Also dont forget to add

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>`

in your manifest. The value of `minSdkVersion` be equal or above 4. But if your `minSdkVersion` is 3 then your `targetSdkVersion` should be equal or above 4

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

to have correct value of width & height.